# Netlify NodeJS Function always returns 'Response to preflight request doesn't pass'

Tags: node.js, lambda, cors, aws-lambda, netlify

I'm trying to create an API endpoint using **Netlify Lambda Function**. The code works perfectly in my local, but always returns `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<my-netlify-project>.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/submit' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

[image]

I'm trying to handle `OPTIONS` and `POST` in my code, but it doesn't seems working. Here is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      if (event.httpMethod === 'OPTIONS') {
            callback(null, { statusCode: '204', headers });
            return;
      }
      if (event.httpMethod === 'POST') {
            callback(null, {
                  statusCode: 200,
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                        success: true,
                  }),
                  headers,
            });
            return;
      }
};
```

And I'm trying to call it from a React app, using `axios` like this:

```
axios.post('https://<my-netlify-project>.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/test', reqObj)
```

And I noticed this error appears on my function invocation

```
10:24:58 PM: error decoding lambda response: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string
```

[image]

What causes the error and how to resolve it?

Comment: For best practices, you should include a return callback on failure of both method types. I know this is an example, but just wanted you to be aware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cors issue

[Known issue using localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/2597114) to make your call.

#### The issue during function invocation

The issue is caused by your header values. All values should be strings. The response in the callback expects these values to be strings.

> error decoding lambda response: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string

```js
const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
  'Access-Control-Max-Age': '2592000',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
};
```

Comment: Tony, you are killing this topic.  I may have to stop monitoring :)

Comment: You guys have taught me well!

Comment: I couldn't understand "They should be strings, so they are added to your response directly". Where I'm doing it wrong and what should I do to resolve this error? @talves

Comment: I made the changes in the above code. Converted the numeric and boolean values to string in `'Access-Control-Max-Age': '2592000'` and `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'`. That solves the error you listed that I quoted above the code.